# validate mutiple textboxes for unique values asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net wizard control. In one step i have four textboxes. I need to make sure that none of the textbox has duplicate value before proceeding to the next step. I can achieve this by adding serverside/clientside function to loop through all the textbox controls and check for the duplicate values, but somehow i feel that this as not the proper way. I searched net and found some links [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1642285.aspx/1) and [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1164975.aspx/1) but nothing seems appropriate. Also i cannot use compare validator as it is for only two controls max.

Do you guys have a better way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u elaborate a bit more..

Comment: you can just write a `javascript function` and then call it on `textchanged` event of every `textbox` and in that javascript function you can write simple compare code...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use CompareValidators for it.

Comment: Using Comparevalidator i can validate only 2 textbox at a time right? otherwise i should have multiple comparevalidators. We should have some better way to achieve this right?

Comment: Maybe on Wizard Next Step Button Click add code-behind to compare textboxes values you need.

Comment: Hope you have not read my question properly :) "I can achieve this by adding serverside/clientside function to loop through all the textbox controls and check for the duplicate values, but somehow i feel that this as not the proper way"